# Silverlight - access string format from Binding in code

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, .net-4.5

I need to find string format from XAML binding in code. Lets say I have data grid where one of the columns is:

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="DD" Binding="{Binding Field4, StringFormat=d}" />
```

I can access the field name like this:

```
dg.Columns
    .OfType<DataGridBoundColumn>()
    .Select(i => (i as DataGridBoundColumn).Binding.Path.Path)
```

**Is there a way to access string format "d" ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
dg.Columns
    .OfType<DataGridBoundColumn>()
    .Select(i => (i as DataGridBoundColumn).Binding.StringFormat)
```

Comment: its unreal! I crawled all other the Binding object in debugger for 20 min and couldnt see the obvious!! thank you